# How can I use ActiveX Conrtols through python to control a Texas Instruments DDC4100 digital controller?

Tags: python, activex

I have been tasked with figuring out how to use python to communicate with the DDC4100 digital controller. The DDC4100 is a component of the DLP Discovery 4100 Development kit. If you are curious about what that is you can click [here.](http://www.ti.com/tool/dlpd4x00kit)

I have been using PythonWin and the pywin32 packages to attempt to communicate with the controller.

I would like to use early binding automation so I used makepy to generate a wrapper for the DDC4100 ActiveX Control module.

```
# -*- coding: mbcs -*-
# Created by makepy.py version 0.5.01
# By python version 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
# From type library 'DDC4100.tlb'
# On Fri Jul 06 10:52:42 2012
'DDC4100 ActiveX Control module'
makepy_version = '0.5.01'
python_version = 0x20703f0

import win32com.client.CLSIDToClass, pythoncom, pywintypes
import win32com.client.util
from pywintypes import IID
from win32com.client import Dispatch

# The following 3 lines may need tweaking for the particular server
# Candidates are pythoncom.Missing, .Empty and .ArgNotFound
defaultNamedOptArg=pythoncom.Empty
defaultNamedNotOptArg=pythoncom.Empty
defaultUnnamedArg=pythoncom.Empty

CLSID = IID('{4AB30830-EFC0-496D-8D38-ACFE2518ECEB}')
MajorVersion = 1
MinorVersion = 0
LibraryFlags = 10
LCID = 0x0

from win32com.client import DispatchBaseClass
class _DDDC4100(DispatchBaseClass):
    'Dispatch interface for DDC4100 Control'
    CLSID = IID('{C4374661-BB24-410F-9BEB-5DED735F4985}')
    coclass_clsid = IID('{5C75C113-9AFC-42AC-8CED-1ABFE27763B5}')

    def AboutBox(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(-552, LCID, 1, (24, 0), (),)

    def AllowMessages(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(11, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def Clear(self, BlockNum=defaultNamedNotOptArg, DoReset=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0), (2, 0)),BlockNum
            , DoReset)

    def ConnectDevice(self, DeviceNum=defaultNamedNotOptArg, SrcFile=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(14, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0), (8, 0)),DeviceNum
            , SrcFile)

    def ConvertImage(self, SrcFile=defaultNamedNotOptArg, DestFile=defaultNamedNotOptArg, MirrorImage=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(4, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((8, 0), (8, 0), (2, 0)),SrcFile
            , DestFile, MirrorImage)

    def DownloadAppsFPGACode(self, FileName=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(12, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((8, 0),),FileName
            )

    def FileToFrameBuffer(self, ImageFile=defaultNamedNotOptArg, MirrorImage=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(6, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((8, 0), (2, 0)),ImageFile
            , MirrorImage)

    def FloatMirrors(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(5, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetActiveXRev(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(13, LCID, 1, (3, 0), (),)

    def GetBlkAd(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(22, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetBlkMd(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(20, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetCOMPDATA(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(32, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetDDCVERSION(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(2, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetDLLRev(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(17, LCID, 1, (3, 0), (),)

    def GetDMDTYPE(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetDriverRev(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(15, LCID, 1, (3, 0), (),)

    def GetEXTRESETENBL(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(40, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetFPGARev(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(47, LCID, 1, (3, 0), (),)

    def GetFirmwareRev(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(16, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetGPIO(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(42, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetNSFLIP(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(34, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetNumDevices(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(46, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetPWRFLOAT(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(38, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetRST2BLKZ(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(24, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetResetComplete(self, waittime=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(49, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((3, 0),),waittime
            )

    def GetRowAddr(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(28, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetRowMd(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(26, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetSTEPVCC(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(30, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetSpeedMode(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(18, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def GetWDT(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(36, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def IsDeviceAttached(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(43, LCID, 1, (11, 0), (),)

    def LoadControl(self):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(45, LCID, 1, (2, 0), (),)

    def LoadData(self, data=defaultNamedNotOptArg, length=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(44, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((16386, 0), (2, 0)),data
            , length)

    def LoadImageFileToBuffer(self, FileName=defaultNamedNotOptArg, ImageBufferPtr=defaultNamedNotOptArg, MirrorImage=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(9, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((8, 0), (16386, 0), (2, 0)),FileName
            , ImageBufferPtr, MirrorImage)

    def LoadToDMD(self, BlockNum=defaultNamedNotOptArg, DoReset=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(7, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0), (2, 0)),BlockNum
            , DoReset)

    def MemToFrameBuffer(self, ImageBufferPtr=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(8, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((16386, 0),),ImageBufferPtr
            )

    def Reset(self, BlockNum=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(10, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),BlockNum
            )

    def SetBlkAd(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(21, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetBlkMd(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(19, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetCOMPDATA(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(31, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetConversionThreshold(self, threshold=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(48, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),threshold
            )

    def SetEXTRESETENBL(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(39, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetGPIO(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(41, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetNSFLIP(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(33, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetPWRFLOAT(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(37, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetRST2BLKZ(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(23, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetRowAddr(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(27, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetRowMd(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(25, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetSTEPVCC(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(29, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    def SetWDT(self, value=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(35, LCID, 1, (2, 0), ((2, 0),),value
            )

    _prop_map_get_ = {
    }
    _prop_map_put_ = {
    }

class _DDDC4100Events:
    'Event interface for DDC4100 Control'
    CLSID = CLSID_Sink = IID('{0CC72AA0-956F-48BD-9118-4446866ECBE3}')
    coclass_clsid = IID('{5C75C113-9AFC-42AC-8CED-1ABFE27763B5}')
    _public_methods_ = [] # For COM Server support
    _dispid_to_func_ = {
    }

    def __init__(self, oobj = None):
        if oobj is None:
            self._olecp = None
        else:
            import win32com.server.util
            from win32com.server.policy import EventHandlerPolicy
            cpc=oobj._oleobj_.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IConnectionPointContainer)
            cp=cpc.FindConnectionPoint(self.CLSID_Sink)
            cookie=cp.Advise(win32com.server.util.wrap(self, usePolicy=EventHandlerPolicy))
            self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie = cp,cookie
    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.close()
        except pythoncom.com_error:
            pass
    def close(self):
        if self._olecp is not None:
            cp,cookie,self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie = self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie,None,None
            cp.Unadvise(cookie)
    def _query_interface_(self, iid):
        import win32com.server.util
        if iid==self.CLSID_Sink: return win32com.server.util.wrap(self)

    # Event Handlers
    # If you create handlers, they should have the following prototypes:


from win32com.client import CoClassBaseClass
# This CoClass is known by the name 'DDC4100.DDC4100Ctrl.1'
class DDC4100(CoClassBaseClass): # A CoClass
    # DDC4100 Control
    CLSID = IID('{5C75C113-9AFC-42AC-8CED-1ABFE27763B5}')
    coclass_sources = [
        _DDDC4100Events,
    ]
    default_source = _DDDC4100Events
    coclass_interfaces = [
        _DDDC4100,
    ]
    default_interface = _DDDC4100

RecordMap = {
}

CLSIDToClassMap = {
    '{C4374661-BB24-410F-9BEB-5DED735F4985}' : _DDDC4100,
    '{5C75C113-9AFC-42AC-8CED-1ABFE27763B5}' : DDC4100,
    '{0CC72AA0-956F-48BD-9118-4446866ECBE3}' : _DDDC4100Events,
}
CLSIDToPackageMap = {}
win32com.client.CLSIDToClass.RegisterCLSIDsFromDict( CLSIDToClassMap )
VTablesToPackageMap = {}
VTablesToClassMap = {
}


NamesToIIDMap = {
    '_DDDC4100Events' : '{0CC72AA0-956F-48BD-9118-4446866ECBE3}',
    '_DDDC4100' : '{C4374661-BB24-410F-9BEB-5DED735F4985}',
}
```

I then used Dispatch to create the control object.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
DDC4100 = Dispatch('DDC4100.DDC4100Ctrl.1')
```

Now when I attept to call one of the functions from the wrapper I am presented with an error.

```
DDC4100.AboutBox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 505, in   __getattr__
ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
com_error: (-2147418113, 'Catastrophic failure', None, None)
```

It seems like the makepy wrapper is not automatically being loaded and so I attempted using the EnsureModule() function form gencache and I still recieve the same error. At this point I do not know what to do since I have gone through this same process with a couple other programs within the registered type libraries and have had no problems. Does anyone see any errors in my methods or logic or know of a different way to go about using an ActiveX control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, that error means the ActiveX control requires a full container.
You could try embedding it in a web page running in IE, which acts as an ActiveX
container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does appear that I need a full container. Now I need to figure out how to use/implement one in python.

Comment: Have you found that it is possible to implement a "full container" in Python?